# Help with Regular Expression

Tags: regular-expressions

How would you write a regular expression that matches exactly the strings over the alphabet {A, . . . , Z} that contains the letter "O" only if they contain the letter "I" and contain at most two "E"’s.

Comment: Is a string with a letter "I" and at most two "E"'s without on "O" valid?

Comment: Yes it would be valid

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. As observed by @q-the-platypus, your condition is ambiguous. Here I will interpret it as the set of words

> (that contains the letter "O" only if it contains the letter "I") and (contains at most two "E"’s).

The first part means that

> if it contains "O", then it contains "I"

or, equivalently, since $p \rightarrow q$ is logically equivalent to "$q$ or not $p$",

> either it contains "I" or it does not contain "O".

Thus your language is the union of the languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, where
\begin{align}
L_1 &= \{ \text{words containing "I" and at most two "E"'s})  \\
L_2 &= \{ \text{words containing no "O" and at most two "E"'s})
\end{align}
Can you finish the exercise now?